# transpose - Turn values from rows into column headers

Tags: oracle

I am trying to turn values from two columns (OPTION_ID, RESPONSE_VALUE) in a table (RESPONSES) into three new columns (CURRENTLY_WORKING, WAGE, HOURS_WORKED). The data currently looks like this:

| Client_id | question_id | option_id | Response_value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1234 | 10187 | Yes | NULL |
| 1234 | 10786 | NULL | 22.80 |
| 1234 | 10876 | NULL | 28 |

Note:

1. Question_Id 10187 = "Are you currently employed"
2. Question_Id 10786 = "What is your hourly wage"
3. Question_Id 10876 = "How many hours per week do you work";

Response_value is a free text field, whereas option_id is a an option the client choses from a list of options, in the case of Question_Id 10187, the options available are "Yes" and "No"

I want to create a table that looks like this:

| Client_id | Currently_Working | Wage | Hours_worked |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1234 | Yes | 22.80 | 28 |

I wrote a query to try a turn the row into columns but it is giving me an error. Here is the query I wrote:

```
SELECT CLIENT_ID, currently_working,
hours_work, wage 
FROM 
(
SELECT CLIENT_ID, QUESTION_ID, OPTION_ID, RESPONSE_VALUE FROM RESPONSES
)rsp 
PIVOT
(
max(OPTION_ID) FOR QUESTION_ID IN ('10187' AS currently_working)) pv1
PIVOT
(
max(RESPONSE_VALUE) FOR QUESTION_ID IN ('10876' AS hours_work,
                                               '10786' AS wage)) pv2
```

The error I get is: SQL Error [904] [42000]: ORA-00904: "QUESTION_ID": invalid identifier

If someone could please help me fix the query so that I can pull the data as I have described above, that would be great.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I would just use a `GROUP BY` query with pivoting logic here:

```sql
SELECT
    Client_id,
    MAX(CASE WHEN question_id = 10187
             THEN option_id END) AS Currently_Working,
    MAX(CASE WHEN question_id = 10786
             THEN Response_value END) AS Wage,
    MAX(CASE WHEN question_id = 10876
             THEN Response_value END) AS Hours_worked
FROM RESPONSES
GROUP BY
    Client_id;
```

Note that ideally your original table should have just a single column for the response values, not two of them.

Comment: It may reference some list of options for referential integrity while `response_value` is a free text. This way I will also prefer to keep domain for predefined list in order to avoid any parsing and need to distinguish between selection and manual input

Comment: thank you for the above query, I was wondering if it is possible to just fix my query above? I am going to add this query to another query, which is why I cannot use the group by function here, if someone could please fix the query I have above to show me how two columns can be pivoted at the same time, that would be great!